# How to match non-printable characters in a python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, non-printing-characters

How do you match non-printable characters in a python regular expression? In my case I have a string that has a combination of printable and non-printable characters.

```
Example String: "Det 3 @ NYY 5 ?7" where the ? is either 0x7f or 0x80.
```

In the above example I need to match 0x7f or 0x80. How do I specify this in a python regex?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a character range.

```
'[\x7f\x80]'
```

Comment: @Ignacio Since _dehlenbe_ seems to be rarely present on SO, I ask you: **'?'** isn't a non-printable character, but _dehlenbe_ used this character as a symbol in **"Det 3 @ NYY 5 ?7"** to represent a non-printable character that have no symbol consisting in only one character ? Is it that ?

Comment: @eyquem: Correct. In globs, the `?` wildcard matches a single character.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try

```
[^[:print:]]
```

for non-printable.

Comment: POSIX character sets aren't supported in python

Comment: it is if  you use the `regex` module

Comment: Works as expected, however it does include white space characters such as \t which may not be the intent.